How can I linearize this equation system?
I have $n = 540$ points: $$\{(x_i,y_i,z_i,t_i, c_i, s_i)\}_{i=1}^{n}$$
Each point gives me 2 equations:
$$
y_i = y_0 + V_y t_i + u_i[s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha)]
$$
$$
z_i = z_0 + V_z t_i - u_i[c_i\cos(\alpha)-s_i\sin(\alpha)]
$$
I want to determine the parameters:
$$
\vec{\beta} = [y_0, z_0, V_y, V_z, \alpha]
$$
the parameters:
$$
[u_1, ...,u_{540}] 
$$
are also not known but I do not care about these values.
I know that:
$$
-4° \leq \alpha \leq + 4°
$$
Also
$$
-1 \leq c_i \leq +1
$$
$$
-1 \leq s_i \leq +1
$$
I could solve this using nonlinear parameter estimation,
however if possible I would like a solution of a linearized version of the system using linear algebra.
I would then use this solution as a starting point for the nonlinear parameter estimation.
Can anyone help me linearize this equation system?

Suppose $s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha)\ne 0$ and $c_i\cos(\alpha) - s_i\sin(\alpha) \ne 0$, then you can solve both equations for $u_i$:
\begin{gather}\frac{y_i-y_0-t_iV_y}{s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha)} = u_i = \frac{z_i-z_0-t_iV_z}{-c_i\cos(\alpha) + s_i\sin(\alpha)} \\
(y_i-y_0-t_iV_y)\underbrace{(-c_i\cos(\alpha) + s_i\sin(\alpha))}_{-A_i} = (z_i-z_0-t_iV_z)\underbrace{(s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha))}_{B_i}.
\end{gather}
If $s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha)= 0$ then you get the equation $y_i - y_0 - t_iV_i = 0$, so the above has gained a root for $c_i\cos(\alpha) - s_i\sin(\alpha) = 0$ and vice-versa. For any fixed $\alpha$ the above results in a system of linear equations in $y_0, V_y, z_0, V_z$:
$$A_i (y_0 + t_i V_y) + B_i(z_0 + t_i V_z) = \underbrace{A_i y_i + B_i z_i}_{b_i} \\ \iff \\
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_1 t_1 & B_1 & B_1 t_1 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ A_n & A_n t_n & B_n & B_n t_n \end{bmatrix}}_{M} \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} y_0 \\ V_y \\ z_0 \\ V_z \end{bmatrix}}_{x} = b.$$
The system is overdetermined so it doesn't necessarily have a solution (especially for the $\alpha$ we fixed.). We can try to find the point that least violates the equality in the $L_2$ norm: $M^TMx = M^Tb$. Then $x = (M^TM)^{-1}M^Tb$. Since the matrix is $4\times 4$ it can be inverted even in closed form. Note that both $M$ and $b$ depended on our choice of $\alpha$, and thus $x$ also depends on that. Having the solution $x$ you could try to iterate this process, by next finding the next $\alpha$ from this $x$.
\begin{align}(y_i-y_0-t_iV_y)(-c_i\cos(\alpha) + s_i\sin(\alpha)) &= (z_i-z_0-t_iV_z)(s_i\cos(\alpha)+c_i\sin(\alpha))\\
\underbrace{((z_i-z_0-t_iV_z)s_i + (y_i-y_0-t_iV_y)c_i)}_{C_i}\cos(\alpha) &= \underbrace{((y_i-y_0-t_iV_y)s_i - (z_i-z_0-t_iV_z)c_i)}_{D_i}\sin(\alpha)
\end{align}
We could find the solutions $\alpha = \arctan(C_i/D_i)$, but it may be contradicting for different $i$. On the other hand we can try to satisfy this again in a leas squares sense:
$$\min_{\alpha} \frac{1}{2}\|C\cos(\alpha) - D \sin(\alpha)\|^2_2 = \min_{\alpha}\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (C_i\cos(\alpha) - D_i\sin(\alpha))^2.$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $\alpha$ yields
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(C_i\cos(\alpha) - D_i\sin(\alpha))(-C_i\sin(\alpha)+D_i\cos(\alpha)) = \sum_{i=1}^n-(C_i^2+D_i^2)\sin(2\alpha) + C_iD_i\cos(2\alpha).$$
Setting to zero results in:
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n C_iD_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nC_i^2+D_i^2}.$$
So you could try iterating these two solutions, for example starting with $\alpha^0 = 0$. At step $k$ you compute $x^k = ((M^k)^TM^k)^{-1}(M^k)^Tb^k$ and then $\alpha^{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\arctan\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n C^k_iD^k_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n(C^k_i)^2+(D^k_i)^2}$, where $M^k$ and $b^k$ are constructed based on $\alpha^k$, and $C^k,D^k$ are constructed based on $x^k$. Note that $k$ here is the iteration index and not an exponent.
